# PayPal adaptive payment IPN function call

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

First time I am trying paypal adaptive payments. Everything is working fine, I tested on sandbox and it works well. Now I need to track whether the payment was successful or not? I was looking into IPN. I saw it and I think it will be perfect to make the success call.

Currently I am using the adaptive code generated by paypal, I am just confused where to call the IPN function(I am using this [IPN script](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt))

Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call the IPN function, PayPal calls your IPN script at a pre-specified URL when it wants to notify you of a payment.

(In soviet PayPal, function calls you!)

Comment: but where do I insert the code which I got from IPN code(https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt)

Comment: Anywhere on your site publicly accessible by a constant URL (like www.example.com/myipncode.php). You then need to login to your paypal account, and enter this URL in the IPN settings page somewhere under the IPN URL field.

Comment: is it possible to do it on localhost?

Comment: It has to be accesible by PayPal. If they can't reach your "Instant Payment Notification" code, how are they supposed to "Instantly Notify you of Payments"?

Comment: If you didn't specify the IPN URL within your PayPal Profile, then you can include 'ipnNotificationUrl' within the 'Pay' API request.